# Divergence of the curl of a vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator, curl

I'm trying to prove for an n-dimensional vector field that the divergence of the curl of the vector field is zero. I've been toying around with indexing the elements and placing the elements in a matrix but am going round in circles.

The statement I am trying to prove, take $u$ to be an $n$ dimensional vector field,

I want to show :

$\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times u) = 0$

Comment: You should have six terms, canceling in pairs. Just follow the definitions.

Comment: For an n dimensional vector field only six terms?

Comment: What is the curl of an $n$-dimensional vector field supposed to be?

Comment: Take an $ n$ dimensional vector field u, the statement I'm trying to prove is $\nabla \dot (\nabla \times u) = 0$

Comment: What is $\nabla \times u $ for an $n$ dim vector $u$?

Comment: The curl of the vector field?

Comment: *facepalm emoji* What's your definition of the curl of a vector field in $n$ dimensions?

Comment: Wait is curl not defined for dimensions beyond 3?

Comment: I realise my mistake, I completely forgot cross product is only defined in 3D, forgive me.

Comment: The closest analogue is the difference between the velocity gradient $\nabla u$ and its transpose, but that is a matrix, not a vector.

Comment: You can define the curl of a vector field in an arbitrary pseudo-Riemannian manifold, but that will be a 2-form, not a vector field. Since you can compute the divergence of tensors, we'll still have that the divergence of a curl is zero. When I first read the question, I didn't see the "n-dimensional" part and assumed you were talking about dimension 3 (I figured that if you were asking how to show that the div of a curl is zero, you wouldn't know about the 2-form definition).